# how to retrieve just one record from (non-distinct) column2 for every distinct column1 value?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, distinct

RDBMS - Oracle 11g.

Question: 
I have a table like this -

```
column1   column2
A         111
A         222
A         333
B         444
C         555
C         666
```

I want to write a query that picks up just one record for each distinct column1 value.
The output should be this way:

```
A         111
B         444
C         555
```

I am not worried about which value in corresponding column2 gets picked up. Only constraint is I just want a singe record being fetched for each of the distinct column1 value.

I cannot think of a way to do this without using procedures. Is this possible with just sql queries (no function/ procedure)? Thanks.

Comment: better representation of the table:
(col1, col2) = 
(A,111), 
(A,222), 
(A,333), 
(B,444), 
(C,555), 
(C,666).

Comment: `SELECT column1, min(column2) FROM table GROUP BY column1;`

Comment: why not SELECT distinct column1, column2, FROM table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure

```
SELECT column1, MIN(column2)
  FROM your_table
 GROUP BY column1
```

Since you don't care which `column2` value you get, you could also use `MAX` or many other aggregate functions instead of `MIN`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care, let the column2 be MIN

```
  SELECT column1, 
         MIN(column2) 
    FROM table 
GROUP BY column1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select column1,MIN(column2)
From tableName
group by column1
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c304f/1)